# Iterating through a text file between start and stop words to assemble a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a text file report I need to iterate through, capturing a row number and all errors and warnings associated with that row.  Using the example below, I need to capture the RowID (integer only) and then all of the errors and warnings found below the line with the object's name (disregarding the rest of the text file).

```
***********************************************************
Date/Time:    6/5/2023
FileName:    somefile.txt
Report:        Standard Report
***********************************************************
Success:    1234
Failures:    1234

RowID:    100
Name:    Smith, John
    This person did not meet the criteria because of x,y,z.
RowID:    101
Name:    Smith, Susie
    This is a warning.
    This is an error.
    Criteria was not met.
RowID:    103
Name:    Jones, Bob
    This person had invalid characters in the email field.
```

I have attempted different variations of the following.

```
search_string = "RowID:"
next_search_string = "Name:"

with open('report.txt') as y:
    for line in y:
        if line.startswith(search_string):
            print(line.split(':')[1].strip())
        if line.startswith(next_search_string):
            print(next(y))
            while not (next(y)).startswith(search_string):
                print(next(y))
        if (next(y)).startswith(search_string):
            pass
```

My desired output is:

100, This person did not meet the criteria because of x,y,z. 
101, This is a warning.  This is an error.  Criteria was not met. 
103, This person had invalid characters in the email field.

Answer (score 0):

**updated answer**

The following code can be helpful:

```
import re

with open('report.txt') as file:
    file_content = file.read()

result = re.findall(r"RowID:\s+(?P<rowid>\d+)\s+Name:\s+(?P<name>[\w, ]+)\n\s+(?P<msg>.*?)(?=\nRowID:|$)", file_content, re.DOTALL)

for rowid, person, msg in result:
    msg = re.sub('\n\s+','', msg)
    print(f"{rowid}, {msg}")
```

Then, the output will be as desired:

```
100, This person did not meet the criteria because of x,y,z.
101, This is a warning. This is an error. Criteria was not met.
103, This person had invalid characters in the email field.
```

**NOTE:** In future, if needed, you can use `person` variable too.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Unfortunately, I am not getting the same desired output that you are.  It appears the break is causing a premature reset stopping only after one.  If I alter the break, for some reason I lose row numbers.  I have used your exact code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you try to build a csv file from your input text file.

The common way is to read the file one line at a time, keeping a *state* to know what to do with the current line.

Code could be:

```
import csv

with open('report.txt') as fdin, open('report.csv', 'w', newline='') as fdout:
    wr = csv.writer(fdout)
    initial = True
    msgs = None
    
    for line in fdin:
        if line.startswith('RowID'): # find start of a bloc
            initial = False
            # write the previous bloc if any
            if msgs != None:
                wr.writerow((rowid, ''.join(msgs)))
            # and start recording the bloc
            msgs = []
            rowid = line.split(':')[1].strip()
        elif line.startswith('Name:'):
            continue
        elif not initial:
            msgs.append(line.strip())

    # do not forget the last bloc
    if msgs != None:
        wr.writerow((rowid, ''.join(msgs)))
```

With you sample data I get:

```
100,"This person did not meet the criteria because of x,y,z."
101,This is a warning.This is an error.Criteria was not met.
103,This person had invalid characters in the email field.
```

The csv module has automatically added quotes in the first line because the second fields contains commas.